# How to properly integrate MapStruct with Eclipse? (Including Lombok java agent)

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok, mapstruct

I'm willing to use MapStruct in some official project so I decided to give it some testing first; I'd need to make it work integrated with eclipse and followed all the instructions provided on MapStruct website but ... so far no luck. **Did anyone succeeded on such integration?** and if yes **what can I be missing?**

My test started with something bigger, but when I realized it was not working I decided to use a smaller example, so this is what I did:

- Using openjdk-10.0.1_windows-x64
- downloaded and installed a fresh version of eclipse
  (eclipse-jee-2019-03-R-win32-x86_64)
- installed latest m2e-apt (and mapstruct plugin though not needed for
  this exercise) as suggested in
  http://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/
- downloaded https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples
- imported from git (from within eclipse) mapstruct-clone project
  (looked the basic-est example)
- checked the settings as suggested in
  http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/ (chap 2.1) and
  everything looks good

... no way to persuade eclipse to auto-generate the mapper implementation, I even added the jdt_apt line to the pom.

Here is a snippet of the pom.xml - please refer to he mapstruct-clone project for the whole code.

```
<properties>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
</properties>
```

Expected result would be:

- to find my re-generated classes under
  "target/generated-sources/annotations"  when I save a mapping
  interface
- (as stated by http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/
  " it will set up the MapStruct annotation processor so it runs right
  in the IDE, whenever you save a mapper type. Neat, isn’t it?")
- but do not
- I can only get the classes generated through a "mvn clean install"
  which is good but not that handy

**Important edit: I'm also using the lombok javaagent**

Comment: Other test with "eclipse-jee-2018-12-R-win32-x86_64" also failed

Comment: Other test with "java-se-8u40-ri" (with both <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId> and <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId> dependencies) also faied

Comment: Update: I looked at the logs in eclipse and this is what I have  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mapstruct/ap/spi/AstModifyingAnnotationProcessor

Comment: Another hint, I'm also availing of the lombok eclipse java agent which looks to be an issue per se (https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1159)

Answer (score 4):

I eventually found the solution to the issue ( =D )

- first thanks to Sjaak Derksen from MapStruct team for supporting me
- second thanks to Pavel Horal for posting this solution
  https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1159
- and finally thanks to myself for being so stubborn (well sometimes it
  helps)

The issue was indeed tied to an incompatibility between Lombok java agent and MapStruct.
To get it to work just do what Pavel suggested in his last post and it will work:

> [...] simply remove the SPI registration inside lombok.jar (by deleting META-INF/services/org.mapstruct.ap.spi.AstModifyingAnnotationProcessor) [...]

Comment: Mmm...it seems it doesn't work with lombok 1.18.12. I tried removing that class from the package but the error is still there. Also, if I just use 1.16.12 I don't need to remove that class at al

Answer (score 1):

I actually faced a very similar issue and solved it in a slightly different manner.

1. As descibed by OP make sure this property is declared in the pom.xml:

   `<properties>
           ...
           <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
           ...
    </properties>`
2. Obviously the m2e-apt plugin for eclipse must be installed:
   https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-apt
3. In the pom.xml make sure that mapstruct-processor and lombok are in scope provided.
4. Last but not least: I had to tweak the lombok.jar by adding the `org.mapstruct.ap.spi.AstModifyingAnnotationProcessor.class` file to the jar (see https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1159#issuecomment-328974483).

Tested with Eclipse 2019-03, Lombok 1.18.6 and Mapstruct 1.2.0.Final.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Chris, it's ok if it works, anyway I wouldn't generally feel more comfortable by removing a class file from a jar.